# Why can't I get the output of a command with system() in Perl?

Tags: perl, ipc

When executing a command on the command-line from Perl, is there a way to store that result as a variable in Perl?

```
my $command    = "cat $input_file | uniq -d | wc -l";
my $result     = system($command);
```

`$result` always turns out to be 0.

Comment: Strongly tempted to retag with rtfm. Must... resist... sarcasm...

Answer (score 10):

Use "backticks":

```
my $command    = "cat $input_file | uniq -d | wc -l";
my $result     = `$command`;
```

And if interested in the exit code you can capture it with:

```
my $retcode = $?;
```

right after making the external call.

Answer (score 6):

From [perlfaq8](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html):

---

Why can't I get the output of a command with system()?

You're confusing the purpose of `system()` and backticks (````). `system()` runs a command and returns exit status information (as a 16 bit value: the low 7 bits are the signal the process died from, if any, and the high 8 bits are the actual exit value). Backticks (``) run a command and return what it sent to STDOUT.

```
$exit_status   = system("mail-users");
$output_string = `ls`;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Perl back-ticks to run a shell command, and save the result in an array.

```
my @results = `$command`;
```

To get just a single result from the shell command, you can store it in a scalar variable:

```
my $result = `$command`;
```

If you are expecting back multiple lines of output, it's easier to use an array, but if you're just expecting back one line, it's better to use scalar.

(something like that, my perl is rusty)

Answer (score 1):

You can use backticks, as others have suggested.  That's fine if you trust whatever variables you're using to build your command.

For more flexibility, you can `open` the command as a pipe and read from that as you would a file.  This is particularly useful when you want to pass variables as command line arguments to the program and you don't trust their source to be free of shell escape characters, as `open` in recent Perl (>= 5.8) has the capacity to invoke a program from an argument list.  So you can do the following:

```
open(FILEHANDLE, '-|', 'uniq', 'some-file.txt') or die "Cannot fork: $!\n";
while (<FILEHANDLE>) {
    # process a line from $_
}
close FILEHANDLE or die "child error: $!\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

IPC::System::Simple provides the 'capture' command which provides a safe, portable alternative to backticks. It (and other commands from this module) are highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this a 'contrived' example, because this is 
equivalent:  'uniq -d $input_file | wc -l'.

In almost all my experience, the only reason for putting the results
in to a perl variable, is to parse the later.  In that case, I use
the following pattern:

```
$last = undef;
$lc = 0;
open(FN, "$input_file");
while (<FN>) {
   # any other parsing of the current line
   $lc++ if ($last eq $_);
   $last = $_;
}
close(FN);
print "$lc\n";
```

This also has the added advantages:

- no fork for shell, cat, uniq, and wc
- faster
- parse and collect the desired input